# Using NUnit TestRunner with xml filter

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to use nunits test engine/test runner to run specific test but somehow I can't get the filter to work (it run my test if I use an empty filter).

This is the code so far:

```
        var package = new TestPackage("path/to/dll");
        package.AddSetting("WorkDirectory", Path.GetDirectoryName("path/to/dll"));

        using (ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance())
        {
            engine.WorkDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(dllPath);
            using (NUnit.Engine.ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package))
            {
                var filter = new TestFilter("<filter><tests><test>UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.TestMethod1</test></tests></filter>");
                var result = runner.Run(new TestEventDispatcher(), filter);
                runner.Unload();
                return CreateResult(result);
            }
        }
```

If I try to run this code and check the result I get:

```
        <command-line><![CDATA[".." ]]></command-line><filter><tests><test>UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.TestMethod1</test></tests></filter><test-suite type="Assembly" id="0" name="UnitTestProject2.dll" fullname="...dll" runstate="NotRunnable" testcasecount="1" result="Failed" label="Error" start-time="2018-02-20 20:31:57Z" end-time="2018-02-20 20:31:57Z" duration="0.001" total="1" passed="0" failed="1" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="0"><failure><message><

        ![CDATA[The NUnit 3 driver encountered an error while executing reflected code.]]></message><stack-trace><![CDATA[

     Server stack trace: 
        vid NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.CreateObject(String typeName, Object[] args)
        vid NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Run(ITestEventListener listener, String filter)
        vid NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
        vid System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
        vid System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

        Exception rethrown at [0]: 
        vid System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
        vid System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
        vid NUnit.Engine.ITestEngineRunner.Run(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
        vid NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)]]></stack-trace></failure></test-suite>
```

Am I missing something obvious? I read through documentation here and sounds like this should be the correct way: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Filters

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using?

Comment: Nunit 3.9 and Nunit engine 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the filter with no `<tests>` node, i.e.:

```
<filter><test>UnitTestProject.Class1.Test123</test></filter>
```

For multiple tests, use:

```
<filter><or><test>NUnitTestRunner.Class1.Test123</test><test>NUnitTestRunner.Class1.Test456</test></or></filter>
```

Alternatively, you may use `ITestFilterBuilder`:

Example:

```
using (ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance())
{
    var filterService = engine.Services.GetService<ITestFilterService>();
    var builder = filterService.GetTestFilterBuilder();
    builder.AddTest("UnitTestProject.Class1.Test123");
    var filter = builder.GetFilter();

    using (ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package))
    {
        var result = runner.Run(listener: null, filter: filter);
    }
}
```

Both solutions yields passed test: `total="1" passed="1"`

---

You may look into the source code of the solution at: https://github.com/dariusz-wozniak/StackOverflowAnswers/tree/master/NUnitTestRunner.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple tests, nest them in an `<or>` element. The docs are wrong! I'll fix.

Comment: That worked perfect! I also really liked the TestFilterBuilder, thanks for the tips.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)